# How to implement siblings nodes (XPATH expressions) relation in Java using DOM and XALAN processor

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xalan

Hello everyone I am developing a program in Java to read the XML using XPATH for siblings nodes (elements which are same level)

I am not able to implement below XPATH expression in Java:

`//*:root/*:child1[.='child_value']/following-sibling::*:child2[*:subelement]/*:subelement3/*:subelement4/following-sibling::*:anyelement`

Could any one please suggest any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `*:root` requires XPath 2.0, which isn't supported by Xalan. The simplest solution is to use Saxon instead.

In XPath 1.0 the way to select an element by local name alone is `*[local-name()='root']` which gets a bit cumbersome for an expression like this that includes 7 such selections.

Comment: I appreciate your suggested answer Michael. But for "following-sibling::child2" how can we write in java

Comment: You mean, how can you write it in XPath 1.0? Write `following-sibling::*[local-name()='child2']`.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for this answer. Actually I was trying *[following-sibling='child2'] So I was getting error. But now I got the answer and sorry for killing your time

Comment: If you tried `following-sibling='child2'` then I worry that you're trying to learn this language by trial and error, which is going to be a painful process. You need to understand how it hangs together by doing some reading, rather than just trying to copy examples.